# How can I add a data source in Grafana without changing other files?

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, grafana

I want to write my own data source to grafana but I find I require to modify source files to do that. Currently the source I had to change is `datasourceSrv.js` and I hope I won't find more places that require modifications.

I know grafana uses Angularjs and requirejs so I imagine myself there are ways to add an external data source without changing any other source files, but I can't find a way to do so.

How can I add a datasources without touching other source files?